# How to read the nth line of a Parsed html in R

Tags: html, r, xml-parsing, html-parsing

The readLines function displays all the content of the source page in one line.

```
con = url("target_url_here")
htmlcode = readLines(con)
```

readLines function has concatenated all the lines of the source page in one line. So there is no way I can navigate to the 15th line in the original html source page.

Next approach is to try parsing it using XML package or httr package.

```
library("httr")
html <- GET("target_url_here")
content2 = content(html,as="text")
parsedHtml = htmlParse(content2,asText=TRUE)
```

By printing out the parsedHtml, it retains the html format and displays all the contents as it can be seen in the source page.
Now suppose I want to extract the title, so the function

```
xpathSApply(parsedHtml,"//title",xmlValue)
```

will give the title.

But my question is, how do I navigate to any line say the 15th line of the html? In other words, how can I treat the html as a vector of strings, where each element of the vector is a separate line in the html page/parsed html object.

Comment: Hmm normally `readLines` reads line by line, so that `htmlcode[15]` should give you the 14th line in your 1st example.

Comment: Yeah that will work. But is there any way to go to the 15th line in a parsed HTML object ?

Comment: @NovneetNov Maybe converting it to character and splitting on linefeeds in the veins of `strsplit(as(parsedHtml, "character"), "\n")[[1]][15]`.

Answer (score 17):

Having a better look at [**the docs** for `readLines()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readLines.html), it actually returns:

> *A character vector of length the number of lines read.*

So in your case:

```
con = url("http://example.com/file_to_parse.html")
htmlCode = readLines(con)
```

you can easily do `htmlCode[15]` to access the 15<sup>th</sup> line in the original html source page.

Answer (score 5):

In response to your comment

> But is there any way to go to the 15th line in a parsed HTML object ?

There are a few different ways to do this.  One is mentioned by lukeA in the comments.  Another is to use `capture.output()` to get the parsed html document line-by-line as a character vector.  This example uses the example data from `?htmlParse`

```
library(XML)
f <- system.file("exampleData", "9003.html", package = "XML")
```

Parse an html document:

```
( doc <- htmlParse(f) )
# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
#     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
#     <head>
#     <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 1 September 2005), see www.w3.org">
#     <title>BKA/RIS VwGH - Volltext</title>
#     <base target="_self">
#     </head>
#     <body>
#     VerÃ¶ffentlichungsdatum
# </body>
#     </html>
```

View the parsed document as a character vector:

```
capture.output(doc)
# [1] "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">"
# [2] "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">"                                                                 
# [3] "<head>"                                                                                                        
# [4] "<meta name=\"generator\" content=\"HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 1 September 2005), see www.w3.org\">"         
# [5] "<title>BKA/RIS VwGH - Volltext</title>"                                                                        
# [6] "<base target=\"_self\">"                                                                                       
# [7] "</head>"                                                                                                       
# [8] "<body>"                                                                                                        
# [9] "VerÃ¶ffentlichungsdatum"                                                                                       
# [10] "</body>"                                                                                                       
# [11] "</html>"                                                                                                       
# [12] " "
```

Get (e.g.) the 5th line:

```
capture.output(doc)[5]
#[1] "<title>BKA/RIS VwGH - Volltext</title>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this works great it isn't slick , but it gets the job done.

```
library(XML)
url <-"your desired website"
html <-htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = T)
text <-readLines(url)
text
nchar (text[15])
```